# How to update primary contact value for related tab in Accounts object?

Tags: accountcontactrelation

I hope you can help with the following. I'm new to Apex (<1mth) and not sure if a Trigger should be used or process builder instead to have the **primary contact** update and displayed in the related tabs for the Accounts object.

[image]

The primary contact is shown in the highlights panel but under the related tab just shows Primary contact (0). My question is: What's the best way to solve this?

**Edit:**

I've changed the Primary_contact__c Lookup(Contact) field on the Contact object to Data Type: checkbox. How can i have this checkbox to show on the contacts object in the screenshot below in between Contact Name and Title?

[image]

Edit:

This is what i have done in process builder:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What should the Primary contact be associated with?  Which related contact do you want to be the "primary".  For what it's worth, it looks like you have a Primary_contact__c Lookup(Contact) field on the Contact object

Comment: @BrianMiller thanks. Yes i also had a custom Primary contact on the Contact object. 

Because what i would like to achieve is: there should be a flag on the contact object named "Primary contact". When that flag is checked this should update the primary contact on the account object. One primary contact must be required and the Trigger test should be close to 100% success rate.

Comment: @MoonBoots - Do you already have code written in contact trigger other than for this requirement?

Comment: @RedDevil no, i have tried doing this with process builder. I'mnot sure what the correct configuration should be though. Se screenshot above.

Comment: Is there a validation rule that should be added before adding a field update in process builder? I'm a bit uncertain what steps should be taken beforehand. You guys know which Trailhead module work through these steps?